# Upgrading packages gives "After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used."

Tags: apt

I did `sudo apt-get upgrade` in my terminal and I got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  krb5-locales libgssapi-krb5-2 libk5crypto3 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0
5 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/531 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [O/n]
```

It is the line `After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.` that intrigues me.

I would like to understand why it does not need more (or less) space as it is updating some packages. This `0 B` has already happened to me more than once, so it can't be a coincidence.

Comment: I am not 100% certain. But a fix or an upgrade includes deleting unneeded code or files, etc. Thereby the file-size decreases and no additional space is needed for that upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Upgraded packages *replace* older packages.

Sometimes the new packages are slightly larger or smaller than the older.

Sometimes the new packages are the same size.

Answer (score 0):

upgraded packages are possible to larger or samaller than old packages and if new packages is smaller than old packages than you get some space will be freed that you know by

> sudo apt autoremove

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

after that command line your disk will be free some space 
And also same for the packages are same size.(new packages and old packages)

In two types case you get same output that is

```
**After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used**
```